# Object do not show color in layout but shows in preview render

Tags: objects

I am currently watching a beginner tutorial on youtube and in the middle of the video, my blender suddenly crashes. When I open up my saved blender file I only got a colorless object even I already apply color to the object. But when I go to preview render (F12) it shows the color.

BTW, I set the render engine to cycles. That is probably the cause of the crash

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your 3D View is set to *Solid* mode, if you switch to the [*Material Preview* or *Rendered* mode](https://developer.blender.org/T74825) then you should see the colors in the viewport as well. The crash might be caused by an out-dated graphics driver or unsupported hardware.

Comment: thanks for your help